# Convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(1+x)^{m}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

If $m,n\geq 0$, $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$, where can I assure that the following integral is convergent?:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(1+x)^{m}}dx$$
My first idea was to take some examples... and with them I am quite sure that if $n$ is greater or equal than $m$ then the integral diverges. I assume that this can be proof with some kind of comparison criterium... but I am quite lost.

I have also seen that for sufficiently large $m-n$, the integral converges... but the point is that I don't really know how to calculate a lower bound $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that if $m-n\geq M$, then the integral converges, and if $m-n<M$, it diverges...

Could someone give me some hints? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The change of variable $y=1+x$ may reduce your integral to something related to the Beta function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f :x \mapsto \dfrac{x^n}{(1+x)^m}$ is continuous over $]0, +\infty[$.

Near $0$, one has $f(x) \sim x^n$, so by comparison the integral converges near $0$ iff $n > -1$.

Near $+\infty$, one has $f(x) \sim x^{n-m}$ so by comparison the integral converges near $+\infty$ iff $n-m < -1$.

Finally the integral converges iff $$\boxed{n > -1 \text{ and } n-m < -1}$$